# Handling the "X" close button in WPF under MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm creating a basic database application in WPF, and I have started using the MVVM pattern.

I have a dialog that asks the user to select an item from a `ListBox` and click "OK." After that, I take the item the user clicked from a property in the view model and pass it into another dialog. But if the user clicks "Cancel," I set that value to `null`, and the action is canceled: I don't open the next dialog and return to the main screen. Example:

```
public class SelectEquipmentViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
{
    private bool _selected;

    public Equipment SelectedEquipment
    {
        // Item selected by the user
    }

    // Action for "SelectCommand," which is attached to
    // the "Select" button in the view
    public void ExecuteSelect()
    {
        _selected = true;

        // Fires a RequestClose event in WorkspaceViewModel,
        // which is attached to the view's Close method
        RequestClose();
    }

    public override void RequestClose()
    {
        if (!_selected)
        {
            // The user clicked "Cancel"
            SelectedEquipment = null;
        }

        base.RequestClose();
    }
}
```

This has been working great, but the problem comes if the user clicks the red "X" close button in the window's control box. The `RequestClose` method never gets invoked, and the selected item isn't set to `null`, which is bad.

I've considered attaching the view model to the `Closing` event of the view, but I feel this could get messy if I start creating handlers for all these events.

What would be the "preferred" way of handling this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using the EventToCommand behavior to wire up the Window object's Closing event to a new ExecuteCancel command is pretty clean.

```
public void ExecuteCancel() 
{ 
    _selected = false; 

    // Fires a RequestClose event in WorkspaceViewModel, 
    // which is attached to the view's Close method 
    RequestClose(); 
}
```

Where do you think this will get messy?  If you add a Cancel button, it could use the same ExecuteCancel bits...

Comment: As far as I know, this is the best way to do this in M-V-VM. There are some situations when you still have to put some logic in the code-behind class, as much as you hate doing that with M-V-VM.

Answer (score 0):

Behaviors are what you want to use to execute a command when the user presses the "X" button on window using MVVM.  Check out Reed Copsey's blog here: http://reedcopsey.com/2009/10/09/using-behaviors-to-allow-the-viewmodel-to-manage-view-lifetime-in-m-v-vm/

You can download a sample application [here...](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowCloseBehavior)

I use this method all the time to allow the ViewModel manage the life of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Approach without additional dependencies is described in article [Handling a Window's Closed and Closing events in the View-Model](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73251/Handling-a-Window-s-Closed-and-Closing-events-in-t) and code with example provided. This does not add code behind xaml.

(Thanks to Reed Copsey's [link](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/04/15/attached-property-port-of-my-window-close-behavior/))